# Formatting error with numbered list when using enumitem and reledmac packages

Tags: lists, enumitem, reledmac

**Update:** *The formatting issue is caused by a bug with* `reledmac` *(see comments). Would it be possible to achieve the same output with an alternative setup? Very happy to receive suggestions.*

I am having some formatting issues with numbered lists while using the `enumitem` and `reledmac` packages. I have placed nested lists within a  `ledgroup` using `reledmac` as I want the footnotes (two types) to appear at the end of each section instead of the bottom of the page. (The lists and numbering are as they should.) As shown in the example, spacing between some but not all items is not as it should.

Is there any way to resolve this? Many thanks.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}{\normalfont}{}{}{}
\titlespacing{\section}{0pc}{3pc}{0pc}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[description]{style=standard, labelwidth=3em, leftmargin=!, parsep=0pt, itemsep=0pt, nosep, font=\normalfont}
\setlist[enumerate]{align=left, labelwidth=2em, leftmargin=!, parsep=0pt, itemsep=0pt, nosep}
\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\Roman{enumi}}
\renewcommand{\labelenumii}{\arabic{enumii}.}

\usepackage[series={A, B},noend,noeledsec]{reledmac}
\renewcommand*{\thefootnoteA}{\textit{\alph{footnoteA}}}
\renewcommand*\footnoteruleA{}
\bhooknoteX[A]{\vskip -3pt\noindent} 
\beforenotesX[B]{0pt}
\renewcommand*\footnoteruleB{}
\bhooknoteX[B]{\vskip -3pt\noindent} 
\numberlinefalse

\begin{document}

\begin{ledgroup}
\beginnumbering
\setcounter{footnoteA}{0}
\setcounter{footnoteB}{0}
\pstart

\section*{Section}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item Item 1\footnoteA{This is a test.}
    \item Item 2\footnoteB{This is another test.}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item Item 3
    \end{enumerate}
    \textit{Some text}
    \begin{enumerate}\setcounter{enumii}{1}
        \item Item 4
        \item Item 5
            \begin{enumerate}[label=\alph*.]
                \item Item 6
                \item Item 7
            \end{enumerate}
    \end{enumerate}
    \item Item 8
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item Item 9
        \item Item 10
        \item Item 11
    \end{enumerate}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item Item 12\\
    \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\pend
\endnumbering
\end{ledgroup}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I am sorry to tell you that is a limit of reledmac, and I have no time to debug it.

Comment: Many thanks @Maïeul for your clarification and sorry to hear it won't be fixed in the short term.